# Парсер XML в MySQL

Tags: xml, xmlparser, парсер, php, mysql

**Здравствуйте!** Стоит непростая задача, есть **xml** со следующим содержанием:

```
<offers>

<offer id="3783" available="true">
<url>http://www.site.ru/katalog/item.html?</url>
<price>3040</price>
<currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
<categoryId>20316</categoryId>
<picture>http://www.site.ru/images/image.jpg</picture><store>true</store>
<pickup>true</pickup>
<name>ITV Интеллект Телеметрия (ПО управления поворотными устройствами)</name>
<vendor>ITV</vendor>
<vendorCode> ITV Интеллект Телеметрия (ПО управления поворотными устройствами)</vendorCode>
<description>ПО управления поворотными устройствами (за один порт или IP)</description>
<sales_notes>Товары по предоплате</sales_notes>
<manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>
</offer>
...
...
</offers>
```

Нужно извлечь данные: **`id="3783"`**  и **`<price>3040</price>`** и занести их в базу данных MySQL.

**Начал вот так:**

```
<?
$url = 'td.xml';       //адрес YML-файла

$yml = simplexml_load_file($url);       //Интерпретирует XML-файл в объект

//цикл для обхода по всем товарам
foreach ($yml->offers->offer as $offer) {
        echo '<h1>'.$offer->id.'</h1>';       //выводим на печать артикул 
        echo $offer->price;        //выводим на печать цену
}
?>
```

Но что, то ничего не получается! И еще мне подсказали, что лучше использовать регулярные выражения а не SimpleXML так как он сжирает оперативную память при обработке больших файлов (мой файл порядка 150000 строк и около 9 Мб). Подскажите пожалуйста, а то уже целый день не могу осилить!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярными выражениями теоретически xml можно парсить, но будет много разных "краевых эффектов", когда xml корректный, а текущая регулярка барахлит. Придется сочинять очередную регулярку-костыль.

В своем коде Вы используете DOM парсер - он грузит все в память и потом с результатом можно работать вдоль и в поперек. Но, конечно, это сказывается на потреблении памяти.

Но есть другой подход - SAX парсер. Он поточный - разбирает по кусочку. Прочитал тег - сообщил, прочитал текст - сообщил. Соответственно, памяти выделяется не много, (обычно, пропорционально "вложенности" и "сложности", но не размеру файла). Он очень хорош, если нужно файл один раз прочитать и забыть.

Посмотрите на пример - [PHP read XML file using SAX parser](http://webexplorar.com/php-read-xml-file-using-sax-parser/) - там разбирается что то очень похожее на Вашу задачу.

P.S. В Вашем коде я не увидел никакого вывода в базу. Вывод в браузер также достаточно затратный и если выводить мегабайты текста, то браузер может быть "слабым звеном".

**upd**

Адаптировал код по ссылке:

```
<?php

  $elements   = null;  // просто имя текущей ноды
  $offer = null; // собирает один элемент offer

  // Вызывается, когда встречается открывающий тег.
  // если это offer - создаем массив под него
  function startElements($parser, $name, $attrs)  
  {
      global $offer, $elements;
      if ($name == 'OFFER') {
        $offer = array();
      }
      $elements = $name;
  }

  // Вызывается, когда тег закрывается
  // если это тег offer - печатаем содержимое и вычищаем
  function endElements($parser, $name) 
  {
      global $offer, $elements;
      if(!empty($name)) {
          if ($name == 'OFFER') {
        echo "<h1>$offer[NAME]</h1>\n";
        echo "$offer[PRICE]\n";
        $offer = null;
          }
    $elements = null;
      }
  }

  // Вызывается для текста, заполняем массив
  function characterData($parser, $data) 
  {
      global $offer, $elements;
      if(!empty($data)) {
          if ($elements == 'NAME' || $elements == 'PRICE') {
            $offer[$elements] = trim($data);
          }
      }
  }

  // Собственно, подготавливаем парсер
  $parser = xml_parser_create();

  xml_set_element_handler($parser, "startElements", "endElements");
  xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, "characterData");

  // открываем файл
   if (!($handle = fopen('td.xml', "r"))) {
       die("could not open XML input");
   }

   while($data = fread($handle, 4096)) // читаем по кусочкам
   {
    xml_parse($parser, $data);  // и стравливаем парсеру
   }

   xml_parser_free($parser); // почистим за собой.

?>
```

Для тестов я сгенерировал xml файл на 42000 элементов offer (просто намножил пример с вопроса).  Размер файла - 37 Мбайт. Думаю, это достаточно для тестов.

Приведенный выше код парсил полторы секунды.

Comment: Спасибо @KoVadim, в идеале хотелось бы написать парсер к которому можно обратиться удаленно через fopen()  и делать это время от времени или запускать через CRON на сервере, поэтому и смотрю в сторону регулярных выражений... но сам настолько "зеленый", не могу представить общую конструкцию как это будет... Кто-бы написал, хоть примерно... в интернете много чего показано но подобного нет!

Comment: @KoVadim Браво! Это чемпион по скорости! Пробовал множество вариантов - этот быстрее всех! Спасибо! Как теперь все это в базу добавить...? Каждый элемент по очереди в базу добавлять это скорее всего затормозит процесс!

Comment: В базу добавить - очень просто - там где я вывожу на экран - просто вставьте код, который будет вставлять в базу. Это один INSERT и я думаю, что Вы управитесь. Каждый элемент добавлять в базу может быть медленно, но если перед процессом добавления открыть транзакцию и в самом конце всех добавлений закрыть, то скорость сильно возрастает.  В моих тестах (c sqlite) - десятки раз.

> а как id извлечь из offer

они спрятаны в массиве `$attrs` в `startElements`.

    if ($name == 'OFFER') {
        $offer = array();
        $offer['id'] = $attrs['id'];
    }

Comment: может оно там как то не так записано.

Но по факту - логично, что оно 1 выводит. `print_r` печатает результат на стандартный вывод. В документации есть уточнение на эту тему. Но почему не написать просто

    echo "   <td>". $offer['id'] ."</td>\n";

или выводит пустую строку? в этом случае, мне кажется, нужно писать не id, а ID (в верхнем регистре).

Добавьте в startElement распечатку содержимого `$attrs` с помощью print_r и посмотрите что там.

Comment: @KoVadim Ураа...
     $offer['ID'] = $attrs['ID']    ...вот и все!

Comment: >мне кажется, нужно писать не id, а ID (в верхнем регистре)

Ага, [Attribute names are case-folded on the same criteria as element names][1].


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-element-handler.php

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо тебе Огромное! Очень помог мне! Ну уж чтоб ваще вопрос закрыть полностью - Как это с транзакцией вставлять в базу, хотя бы подсказку....!

Comment: А зачем Вам так много сразу выводить? Я все понимаю, но так много выводить. Обычно выводят по частям. 

Попробуйте для начала вывести просто текстовый файл такого объема в браузер (просто в цикле куча print) и сравните. Скорее всего будет такой же результат.

А вот как это переписать, как правильно завернуть - это тема не одного нового вопроса:)

Answer (score 1):

регулярное выражения для поиска id `<offer[^>]*id=["|'](\d*)["|'][^>]*>`

регулярное выражения для поиска прайса `<price>(\d*)<\/price>`

Comment: Спасибо! Вот только как правильно написать не представляю... подскажи если не сложно!

Comment: я бы сделал вот так
``
$xml = file("xml.xml");
$i = 0;
$result = array();
foreach($xml as $line){
    
    preg_match('/<offer[^>]*id=["|\'](\d*)["|\'][^>]*>/', $line, $idMatch);
    preg_match('/<price>(\d*)<\/price>/', $line, $priceMatch);
    
    if ($idMatch){
        $id = $idMatch[1];
        $result[$i]['id']=$id;
    }

    if ($priceMatch){
        $price = $priceMatch[1];
        $result[$i]['price']=$price;
        $i++;
    }

}
print_r($result);
``

но при таком подходе нужно чтобы довольно четко сохранялась структура вашего xml