# Php парсер xml-файла

Tags: xml, xmlparser, парсер, php

**Здравствуйте!** Подскажите по парсеру, есть **xml** - содержание файла:

```
<fishes>
<fish id="147">
<rule><![CDATA[Natura]]></rule>
<pics>
<pic>http://site.ru/0001.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0007.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0006.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0005.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0002.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0008.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0003.jpg</pic>
<pic>http://site.ru/0004.jpg</pic>
</pics>
<name><![CDATA[Roset]]></name>
<stran>Испания></stran>
<opt>int</opt>
</fish>
...
...
</fishes>
```

С помощью найденного решения в параллельной ветке [php - Парсер XML в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/332297/php-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-xml-%D0%B2-mysql)
удается распарсить необходимые текстовые значения тегов.

Код решения:

```
<?php

$elements   = null;  // просто имя текущей ноды
$fish = null; // собирает один элемент fish

// Вызывается, когда встречается открывающий тег.
// если это fish - создаем массив под него
function startElements($parser, $name, $attrs)  
{
  global $fish, $elements;
  if ($name == 'FISH') {
    $fish = array();
    $fish['ID'] = $attrs['ID'];
  }
  $elements = $name;
}

// Вызывается, когда тег закрывается
// если это тег fish - печатаем содержимое и вычищаем
function endElements($parser, $name) 
{
  global $fish, $elements;
  if(!empty($name)) {
      if ($name == 'FISH') {
    echo "<p>$fish[ID]</p>\n";
    echo "<p>$fish[NAME]</p>\n";
    echo "<p>$fish[RULE]</p>\n";
    echo "<p>$fish[STRAN]<p>\n";
    echo "<p>$fish[PIC]<p>\n";
    $fish = null;
      }
$elements = null;
  }
}

// Вызывается для текста, заполняем массив
function characterData($parser, $data) 
{
  global $fish, $elements;
  if(!empty($data)) {
      if ($attrs == 'ID' || $elements == 'NAME' || $elements == 'RULE' || $elements == 'STRAN' || $elements == 'PIC' ) {
        $fish[$elements] = trim($data);
      }
  }
}

// Собственно, подготавливаем парсер
$parser = xml_parser_create();

xml_set_element_handler($parser, "startElements", "endElements");
xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, "characterData");

// открываем файл
if (!($handle = fopen('catalog_test.xml', "r"))) {
   die("could not open XML input");
}

while($data = fread($handle, 4096)) // читаем по кусочкам
{
 xml_parse($parser, $data);  // и стравливаем парсеру
}

xml_parser_free($parser); // почистим за собой.

?>
```

Но **не получается вывести все ссылки, выводится только последнее значение тега `<pic>`**. Второй день пытаюсь найти что-нибудь, и безрезультатно.

Comment: @wualla, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что Вы при обработке данных просто перезаписываете параметр 'PIC':

```
if ($attrs == 'ID' || $elements == 'NAME' || $elements == 'RULE' || $elements == 'STRAN' || $elements == 'PIC' ) {
        $fish[$elements] = trim($data);
      }
```

Парсер открывает элемент 'FISH', перебирает в нем все элементы 'PIC' и присваивает переменной в массиве значение, а так как Вы не разделяете их, то в итоге остается только последнее значение.

Если файл не такой большой, то можно использовать **simplexml_load_file**, там и доступ к элементам намного проще и красивей получится.

**Обновление**

Проще всего сделать вторую проверку в `characterData`, отдельно для 'PIC', и в ней складывать элементы в под-массив. А из первой проверки убрать 'PIC'.

```
if($elements == 'PIC'){ $fish[$elements][] = trim($data); }
```

Доступ к элементам будет через числовой индекс, начиная с 0. Советую так же ознакомиться с документацией по массивам PHP, и провести пару-тройку тренировок на примерах.

Comment: Может подскажите как можно разделить эти элементы, чтобы каждому элементу 'PIC' было присвоено свое значение в массиве? Целый день сегодня потратил, чтобы это понять, все тщетно...
файл большой...